# Ternary Operator within if-statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, ternary-operator

Is it possible to use a ternary operator within an if-statement in Python?

Simplified example:

`if (do() if boolean expression else otherwise()): ...`

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Why would you want to do this though?  It's more Pythonic to use a variable to capture the boolean and then use that in the `if` statement.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
You have on-line documentation and a Python interpreter with which to experiment.  How did those not answer your question?

Comment: As others mentioned it, this is not very readable

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but It would be better to use an if-statement as mixing both can add unnecessary complexity.

```
if boolean_condition and do() or not boolean_condition and otherwise():
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes certainly, you can just run some trials:

```
if(1 if 50<10 else 0):
    print 5
```

Does nothing.

```
if(1 if 5<10 else 0):
    print 5
```

Prints 5